# Laravel 8: is it fine to leave unused functionality config files untouched in terms of performance, correctness and security?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Laravel 8 has config files for auth, mail, broadcasting, queue, services, session .etc, but I am not using those functionalities for my specific application.

Is it fine to leave the config files (and corresponding .env settings) untouched, or is it better to delete those files?

I am talking about both in terms of performance, execution correctness and security, but not in terms of code readability here. In other words I am talking about "real effects to my application".

Comment: How do you think files with a total size of 10KB is somehow possible to affect your performance?

Comment: What I am afraid of is actually the framework is doing something behind the doors that if the files exist extra processing time will be consumed, rather than i/o reading the files.

Comment: If you are not using them I'd say don't delete them you most likely will break something in your app. If you wan't to improve performance and you don't need some of the framework features maybe laravel isn't the right platform for you. Deleting core features of the framework sound like a risky idea.

Comment: But I wouldn't really imagine there are many websites that uses both "mail" feature and "broadcasting" features though. I would believe most websites wouldn't use broadcasting, is it just better to keep the config setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**:

it's not recommended to do something like that if you don't wanna go out from laravel's ecosystem.

**TL;DR**:

Since Laravel version 5.1 there was some general changes about the configurations. It means it for your v8 as well.

In every today's laravel project you have **bootstrap/cache** folder, which includes some **bootstrap/cache/.gitignore** file for ignoring other files. That ignored (3-4) files are actually cached files, which were creating automatically, and you can't do anything about that in-the-box.

The **bootstrap/cache/config.php** file is responsible for all the configurations, and it's creating as from **config/*.php** config files, as well as from all the config files from vendored dependencies. It means, everytime when you're using your laravel app, that file will be created automatically using

- all the project-specific configurations
- all the vendored configurations
- environment variables from .env.

**Note**: there might be a case, when some in-box package (like laravel's default mail.php config file) or some 3rd-party package (unlikely, but anyway) could not have their own config file, so in vendor core codes there may be a confidence, that it can get some configs exactly from their apropriate **config/*.php** file, so in that case it's not recommended to delete that. For example, when you're deleting **config/mail.php**, and you're using that, in both cases you'll have approximately the same cached config, except some small mail-config-features (optimization there only approx. ~60 lines of human readable lines), but in that case you can't use laravel's Mailing functionality.

The sense is that when you want to override some configs, you're just creating some own config file(s) (in general with the same name as it's in vendor's appropriate location), so that laravel can do caching from **config/*.php**, but not from **vendor/username/package/path/to/config.php**.

So for optimization, laravel doing that caching process once, and after whole usage it will retrieve conifigs only from bootsrapped **bootsrap/cache/config.php** configs.

That's why everytime you're changing something in some **config/*.php** file or/and in **.env** file, you need to clean (manually) and it will be created again automatically
OR just:
there's a in-build command like:

```
# this will clean all the application caches
php artisan optimize
# or only for cleaning and recreating config
# this is an old-school version, but still used
php artisan config:cache
```

All this means, that you don't need to delete some config file from **config/*.php**, because laravel will check is the cached file exists, (if not, then it will create caches anyway from vendor configs), and all the time it will read them from cached files.

**Conclusion**: All this means, that

- that is not related with security and there's nothing to do about that
- if you feel that decreasing the cached **bootstrap/config.php** file content from 1566 lines to 1500 lines it's a way of optimization, then you're free to do that, but you should know that it could make some problems in future.

**Subjective recommendation**: in human language, i don't recommend to do something like that. Anyway you can do that, may you can improve something, that couldn't do another contributors yet. But it will not give a real effect to your app.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have looked at the 'bootstrap/cache/config.php' after deleted the broadcasting.php in config folder, but it seems that the missing broadcast config really is not generated any more, rather than create caches anyway from vendor configs.

Comment: Yeah, as i said that because it's an in-box feature.. the same is for mail.php.You can delete that broadcast.php, and regenerate caches again without that, but in that case you'll get an error when you will use something related with broadcasting. it's just your decision